# ViewController addSubview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, addsubview

I am nearly going crazy:

```
GolOlurActionViewController *golOlur = [[GolOlurActionViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:golOlur.view];
```

I have the above code, and I call this in an `IBACtion` inside a `ViewController`. `GolOlurActionViewController` is a `ViewController` as you all can guess.

When the process starts, golOlur's `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` methods are called but the view is not presented.

I have tried everything I know but could not solve this.

Comment: Wait, I misread your code.  Why are you trying to add another view controller's view as a subview to this one?  That's not how ViewControllers work.  You create a view controller to *control* the view.  It should be pushed to become the default controller when used.  If you just need to create a `golOlur` view to add to your current view, you need to subclass `UIView`--not `UIViewController`.

Comment: Also, when the IBAction method ends, you have a problem.  If you're using ARC, your `GolOlurActionViewController` will be released, leading to crashes if you interact with the view you've grabbed from it. If it's not ARC, it's a memory leak.

Comment: @iremk I agree with Wendi that this notion, of using `addSubview` (which is surprisingly prevalent) to transition to a new view, represents a fundamental confusion of the role of view controllers vs views. _Do not use `addSubview` to transition between view controller's main views!_

Comment: @PhillipMills You're right of course, but I think you're solving a symptom (either leaking or crashing depending upon non-ARC or ARC), rather than the problem. People should not be using `addSubview` to transition between views.

Comment: @RobertRyan True, though I didn't intend it so much as attempting to solve anything as trying to add some extra detail concerning how this whole pattern is something that also triggers other SDK problems.  When I see this, I get the idea people want to create container view controllers without taking the necessary steps to do that right.

Comment: @PhillipMills Understood and agreed. I just wanted to make sure iremk didn't take your comment and try to solve that rather than the root problem. If he's doing controller containment (which I think is unlikely) and he's adding the first child view, then our counsel would be (a) initialize controller properly; and (b) call `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController`, too. But generally when I see people on SO using `addSubview` in conjunction with controllers, they are not doing containment, but rather are simply unfamiliar with how to transition between controllers properly.

Comment: in my situation i had to use viewcontroller because when i am adding this subview besides from transtion or modal , i need to know when view loaded when view appeared to control the connections , animations and so on .. anyways i just deleted the .xib file and imported it again it started working , there was not a problem with my code.. thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You really should not use `addSubview` if your intent is to transition between views. If you do so, you won't receive rotation events because you are allowing your view controller hierarchy to get out of sync with the view hierarchy. You should use `addSubview` only to add a true subview (e.g. a `UILabel`, a `UIImageView`, a `UIButton`, etc., or, the child view if doing proper view controller containment, etc.) to a view. The use of `addSubview` to transition between views represents a fundamental confusion between view controllers and views.

The key to proper management of your views is to make sure that your view controller hierarchy is synchronized with your view hierarchy. The easiest way to do this is to do your transitioning between view controllers and let them take care of the presentation of their views. Thus, if you're using NIBs, it would generally be:

```
GolOlurActionViewController *golOlur = [[GolOlurActionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:golOlur animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or, NIBs with navigation controller:

```
GolOlurActionViewController *golOlur = [[GolOlurActionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:golOlur animated:YES];
```

Or, if you're using storyboards (then again, if you were using storyboards, you'd probably be using segues and wouldn't need any of this, but just for the sake of completeness):

```
GolOlurActionViewController *golOlur = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GolOlurActionView"];
[self presentViewController:golOlur animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and if your storyboards are using navigation controllers:

```
GolOlurActionViewController *golOlur = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GolOlurActionView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pushViewController:golOlur animated:YES];
```

In the unlikely event you're trying to do controller containment, let us know, because that's slightly different (requiring calls to `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController`), but if you're doing basic transitioning between views, the proper initialization of your controller and the subsequent call to `presentViewController` or `pushViewController` should do it for you.

**Update:**

As a quick aside, if you are using storyboards (I don't think you are, but just in case), rather than `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`, I might actually suggest that you define a segue on the storyboard, supply it with an identifier string in Interface Builder, and then use the following code to transition to the next scene:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier" sender:self];
```

If you do it this way, it takes care of instantiating your controller for you and the flow of your entire app will be accurately represented in the storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is that you are expecting the view in a storyboard or .xib to show up when you create a UIViewController the way you are, which will not work. You need to either wire up a push segue in the storyboard (which will require a `UINavigationController`), or present the new controller modally, which you can also do in the storyboard. If you have a a nib for this ViewController, you can do this:

```
 CustomViewController *controller = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController.xib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

 [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:NULL];
```