# App crash on addsubview when enable ARC

Tags: ios, crash, automatic-ref-counting, addsubview

When I used tradition function

```
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
```

or

```
   [self presentModalViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];,
```

Everything is ok. But when I used

```
   [self.view addSubview:viewcontroller.view];
```

I can't do anything in next view, all view's membory pointer has gone. And it crashes all the time.

Comment: If your intention is transition between views you should not use `addSubview`, Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710463/viewcontroller-addsubview

Comment: Where have you declared viewcontroller object?

Comment: Show error log.. that may help us to solve your problem.

Comment: @Deepesh I have seen that question before,but i do that with out arc,it's fine.I just want to know what's arc doing in addsubview.

Comment: @Alexwang: Ok, Could you provide log of the crash, that might be helpful.

Comment: You shouldn't add another view controller's view as a subview of your view unless you also make that controller a child view controller.

Comment: Sorry,can't catch log,It break in system thread.Just create an Arc project,and addsubview an viewcontroller,nslog one of them view,I'm sure you can see that.

Comment: Thanks everyone.I declare viewcontroller object in .h file,It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your viewController object is declared locally. Make it class level variable (declare in .m file). Reason why your app crashes is you declare object locally and it is released after that function is finished. So no object for addSubView. When you push or present object is retained once and hence not released and application works. So if you want to use addSubView then make it class level variable so that it wont be released.